# Socket.io only works local

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i watched a laracast video about websockets(socket.io) and tried it myself. On localhost it is working just fine, but when i try to run it on a server i just get errors.

My **socket.js:**

```
var server = require('http').Server();

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var Redis = require('ioredis');

var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('report-created');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message){
message = JSON.parse(message);

io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

**Client:**

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var socket = io('IPFromServer:3000');
    new Vue({
        el: 'body',
        data: {
            reports: []
        },

        ready: function(){
            socket.on('report-created:App\\Events\\ReportCreated', function(report){
                console.log(report["reportCreated"]);



                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                window.location.replace("http://autoreport.dev/fileentry/get/" + report["reportCreated"]);

            }.bind(this));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Like i said, it is working on Localhost just fine, but not on a server i always get this error message:

```
GET ...socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1446734287420-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT   socket.io.min.js:1
```

I googled a lot, but can not find any answer. Maybe some of you know a solution.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

In the **server script** change

```
server.listen(3000);
```

for

```
server.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0')
```

And in your **client** script change

```
var socket = io('IPFromServer:3000');
```

for

```
var server = 'IPFromServer:3000',
    socket = io.connect(server);
```

And make sure that server string is correct

Comment: In lsof -i the ports seems to be open and listening

node      27307       root   10u  IPv4 303738      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
node      27307       root   11u  IPv4 303739      0t0  TCP localhost:45576->localhost:6379 (ESTABLISHED)

I do not know what the second node is